# View all functions from the SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, function, sql-server-2005

How can I view all the functions (built in) in a SQL Server database using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: When you say "functions", do you mean "user-defined functions" or do you mean "any programmatic database object, including stored procedures"?

Comment: all those 'table value functions', 'scalar valued functions', 'system functions' etc.

Comment: + which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Can you give an example of a function that you want to see, but doesn't show up in the regular tree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will return all user-defined functions. I'm not sure what you mean by "build-in" functions.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE RIGHT(type_desc, 8) = 'FUNCTION'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects where type in ('FN','AF','FS','FT','IF','TF')
```

Here are the types:

```
--AF = Aggregate function (CLR)
--C = CHECK constraint
--D = DEFAULT (constraint or stand-alone)
--F = FOREIGN KEY constraint
--PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint
--P = SQL stored procedure
--PC = Assembly (CLR) stored procedure
--FN = SQL scalar-function
--FS = Assembly (CLR) scalar function
--FT = Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
--R = Rule (old-style, stand-alone)
--RF = Replication filter procedure
--SN = Synonym
--SQ = Service queue
--TA = Assembly (CLR) trigger
--TR = SQL trigger 
--IF = SQL inlined table-valued function
--TF = SQL table-valued function
--U = Table (user-defined)
--UQ = UNIQUE constraint
--V = View
--X = Extended stored procedure
--IT = Internal table
```

Here is a list of all system stored procs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187961.aspx

Comment: i see all table valued and scalar valued functions but not the system functions. Anyclue?

Comment: When we use 'sys.all_objects' is it returning all the objects from all the database or the database against which you are running the query?

Comment: all the objects in the database you're running the query on. System functions are all in the 'sys' schema.

Comment: but didn't you say you wanted to see them through the management studio?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft doesn't seem to have any public list of built-in functions in T-SQL or SQL Server, but you can reconstruct such a list by using their documentation's function-list (from the table-of-contents) and your web-browser's dev-tools window.

1. Open a Chromium-based browser and navigate to the "Functions > Functions" page.

   - As of October 2022, that's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/functions
2. Expand all of the sub-category nodes under "Functions" in the table of contents.

   - Left-click the arrow to expand the node, but **don't** click on the text itself (as that will navigate-away from the current page).
   - So you should have something like this (click to zoom): 
     [image]
3. Open your browser's Developer Tools window.
4. Use the "Select an element in the page" feature and click on the top-level "Functions" node, like so: 
   [image]
5. The node will now be selected in the **Elements** tab, so then right-click the node and choose "Store as global variable".

   - Like so: 
     [image]
6. Assuming it saved it to `temp1` then run this in the console:

   - (You can copy+paste multiple statements/lines into the console, that's fine)

     ```
     var lis  = Array.from( temp1.querySelectorAll(':scope > ul.tree-group > li.tree-item > ul.tree-group > li') );
     var lis2 = lis.map( li => ( { li, first: li.parentElement.querySelector(':scope > li:first-child > a') } ) ).filter( t => t.li.textContent !== t.first.textContent );
     var texts = lis2.map( t => ( { name: t.li.textContent, category: t.first.textContent } ) );
     var joined = texts.map( t => t.category + ": " + t.name ).join( "\r\n" );
     ```
7. Then run `console.log( joined );` to get the list of functions as text.

...or use this list:

- Note this list includes some newly-added functions only available in SQL Server 2022 (such as `GREATEST`) or those only available in Azure Synapse Analytics and Analytics Platform System (formerly known as *Parallel Data Warehouse*), such as `VERSION`.

```
Aggregate:

    APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT
    APPROX_PERCENTILE_CONT
    APPROX_PERCENTILE_DISC
    AVG
    CHECKSUM_AGG
    COUNT
    COUNT_BIG
    GROUPING
    GROUPING_ID
    MAX
    MIN
    STDEV
    STDEVP
    SUM
    VAR
    VARP

Analytic:

    CUME_DIST
    FIRST_VALUE
    LAG
    LAST_VALUE
    LEAD
    PERCENTILE_CONT
    PERCENTILE_DISC
    PERCENT_RANK

Bit manipulation:

    LEFT_SHIFT
    RIGHT_SHIFT
    BIT_COUNT
    GET_BIT
    SET_BIT

Collation

    COLLATIONPROPERTY
    TERTIARY_WEIGHTS

Configuration:
    
    @@DBTS
    @@LANGID
    @@LANGUAGE
    @@LOCK_TIMEOUT
    @@MAX_CONNECTIONS
    @@MAX_PRECISION
    @@NESTLEVEL
    @@OPTIONS
    @@REMSERVER
    @@SERVERNAME
    @@SERVICENAME
    @@SPID
    @@TEXTSIZE
    @@VERSION

Conversion:

    CAST
    CONVERT
    PARSE
    TRY_CAST
    TRY_CONVERT
    TRY_PARSE

Cryptographic:

    ASYMKEY_ID
    ASYMKEYPROPERTY
    CERTPROPERTY
    CERT_ID
    CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM
    DECRYPTBYASYMKEY
    DECRYPTBYCERT
    DECRYPTBYKEY
    DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY
    DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOCERT
    DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE
    ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY
    ENCRYPTBYCERT
    ENCRYPTBYKEY
    ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE
    HASHBYTES
    IS_OBJECTSIGNED
    KEY_GUID
    KEY_ID
    KEY_NAME
    SIGNBYASYMKEY
    SIGNBYCERT
    SYMKEYPROPERTY
    VERIFYSIGNEDBYCERT
    VERIFYSIGNEDBYASYMKEY

Cursor:

    @@CURSOR_ROWS
    @@FETCH_STATUS
    CURSOR_STATUS

Data type:

    DATALENGTH
    IDENT_CURRENT
    IDENT_INCR
    IDENT_SEED
    IDENTITY
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY

Date & time:
    
    @@DATEFIRST
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    CURRENT_TIMEZONE
    CURRENT_TIMEZONE_ID
    DATE_BUCKET
    DATEADD
    DATEDIFF
    DATEDIFF_BIG
    DATEFROMPARTS
    DATENAME
    DATEPART
    DATETIME2FROMPARTS
    DATETIMEFROMPARTS
    DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS
    DATETRUNC
    DAY
    EOMONTH
    GETDATE
    GETUTCDATE
    ISDATE
    MONTH
    SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS
    SWITCHOFFSET
    SYSDATETIME
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET
    SYSUTCDATETIME
    TIMEFROMPARTS
    TODATETIMEOFFSET
    YEAR

Graph:
    
    EDGE_ID_FROM_PARTS
    GRAPH_ID_FROM_EDGE_ID
    GRAPH_ID_FROM_NODE_ID
    NODE_ID_FROM_PARTS
    OBJECT_ID_FROM_EDGE_ID
    OBJECT_ID_FROM_NODE_ID

JSON:
    
    ISJSON
    JSON_OBJECT
    JSON_ARRAY
    JSON_VALUE
    JSON_QUERY
    JSON_MODIFY
    JSON_PATH_EXISTS

Mathematical:
    
    ABS
    ACOS
    ASIN
    ATAN
    ATN2
    CEILING
    COS
    COT
    DEGREES
    EXP
    FLOOR
    LOG
    LOG10
    PI
    POWER
    RADIANS
    RAND
    ROUND
    SIGN
    SIN
    SQRT
    SQUARE
    TAN

Logical:
    
    CHOOSE
    GREATEST
    IIF
    LEAST

Metadata:

    @@PROCID
    APP_NAME
    APPLOCK_MODE
    APPLOCK_TEST
    ASSEMBLYPROPERTY
    COL_LENGTH
    COL_NAME
    COLUMNPROPERTY
    DATABASEPROPERTYEX
    DB_ID
    DB_NAME
    FILE_ID
    FILE_IDEX
    FILE_NAME
    FILEGROUP_ID
    FILEGROUP_NAME
    FILEGROUPPROPERTY
    FILEPROPERTY
    FILEPROPERTYEX
    FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY
    FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY
    INDEX_COL
    INDEXKEY_PROPERTY
    INDEXPROPERTY
    NEXT VALUE FOR
    OBJECT_DEFINITION
    OBJECT_ID
    OBJECT_NAME
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME
    OBJECTPROPERTY
    OBJECTPROPERTYEX
    ORIGINAL_DB_NAME
    PARSENAME
    SCHEMA_ID
    SCHEMA_NAME
    SCOPE_IDENTITY
    SERVERPROPERTY
    STATS_DATE
    TYPE_ID
    TYPE_NAME
    TYPEPROPERTY
    VERSION

Ranking:

    DENSE_RANK
    NTILE
    RANK
    ROW_NUMBER

Replication:

    PUBLISHINGSERVERNAME

Security:

    CERTENCODED
    CERTPRIVATEKEY
    CURRENT_USER
    DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID
    HAS_DBACCESS
    HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME
    IS_MEMBER
    IS_ROLEMEMBER
    IS_SRVROLEMEMBER
    LOGINPROPERTY
    ORIGINAL_LOGIN
    PERMISSIONS
    PWDENCRYPT
    PWDCOMPARE
    SESSION_USER
    SESSIONPROPERTY
    SUSER_ID
    SUSER_NAME
    SUSER_SID
    SUSER_SNAME
    SYSTEM_USER
    USER
    USER_ID
    USER_NAME

String:

    ASCII
    CHAR
    CHARINDEX
    CONCAT
    CONCAT_WS
    DIFFERENCE
    FORMAT
    LEFT
    LEN
    LOWER
    LTRIM
    NCHAR
    PATINDEX
    QUOTENAME
    REPLACE
    REPLICATE
    REVERSE
    RIGHT
    RTRIM
    SOUNDEX
    SPACE
    STR
    STRING_AGG
    STRING_ESCAPE
    STUFF
    SUBSTRING
    TRANSLATE
    TRIM
    UNICODE
    UPPER

System:

    $PARTITION
    @@ERROR
    @@IDENTITY
    @@PACK_RECEIVED
    @@ROWCOUNT
    @@TRANCOUNT
    BINARY_CHECKSUM
    CHECKSUM
    COMPRESS
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY
    CONTEXT_INFO
    CURRENT_REQUEST_ID
    CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID
    DECOMPRESS
    ERROR_LINE
    ERROR_MESSAGE
    ERROR_NUMBER
    ERROR_PROCEDURE
    ERROR_SEVERITY
    ERROR_STATE
    FORMATMESSAGE
    GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT
    GETANSINULL
    HOST_ID
    HOST_NAME
    ISNULL
    ISNUMERIC
    MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION
    NEWID
    NEWSEQUENTIALID
    ROWCOUNT_BIG
    SESSION_CONTEXT
    SESSION_ID
    XACT_STATE

System Statistical:

    @@CONNECTIONS
    @@CPU_BUSY
    @@IDLE
    @@IO_BUSY
    @@PACK_SENT
    @@PACKET_ERRORS
    @@TIMETICKS
    @@TOTAL_ERRORS
    @@TOTAL_READ
    @@TOTAL_WRITE

Text & Image:

    TEXTPTR
    TEXTVALID

Trigger:

    COLUMNS_UPDATED
    EVENTDATA
    TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL
    UPDATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Not on the SSMS, but in TSQL

```
select * from master..sysobjects where type = 'fn'
```

But do you mean also DMV's, sprocs etc?

Answer (score 0):

To get all User Defined function of a particular database use the below code

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT name AS function_name
,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
,type_desc
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%';
GO
```