# How to list all builtin SQL functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Microsoft has a good documentation for SQL API, but it is for humans.

Is it possible to retrieve list of all builtin functions with types programmatically?

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM information_schema.routines
```

return just user defined ones

```
select name from sys.objects o
```

there is no `isnull` function e.g.

`sys.system_objects` sounds like a right place.
There is a `fn_numberOf1InVarBinary`, but `isnull` is not listed.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2766639/73226 though the accepted answer misses the point of what built in functions are. Essentially there is no DMV that has the builtin functions like `ISNULL`, `CHARINDEX` etc